# I'm having output errors. Can someone explain what I've done wrong?

Tags: java

For my class, I have to write a java application that prompts for the person's information , instantiates an object of class Health Profile for that person and prints the information from that object — including the person's First name , last name , gender , date of birth , height and weight — then calculates and prints the person's age in years , BMI , maximum heart rate and target - heart - rate range . It should also display the BMI values.

If you look at the output, you can see which part of the code go through. I am completely stumped. I'm still at a beginner level in java.

Here is the first part of the code, the Healthprofile:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HealthProfile {

String firstName;
String lastName;
char gender;
int BirthMonth;
int BirthDay;
int BirthYear;
int height;
int weight;

public HealthProfile(String fName, String lName, char Genderr, int birthMonth, int birthDay, int birthYear, int heightt, int weightt){
firstName = fName;
lastName = lName;
gender = Genderr;
BirthMonth = birthMonth;
BirthDay = birthDay;
BirthYear = birthYear;
height = heightt;
weight = weightt;



}

HealthProfile() {

}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setBirthMonth(int BirthMonth) {
    this.BirthMonth = BirthMonth;
}

public int getBirthMonth() {
    return BirthMonth;
}

public void setBirthDay(int BirthDay) {
    this.BirthDay = BirthDay;
}

public int getBirthDay() {
    return BirthDay;
}

public void setBirthYear(int BirthYear) {
    this.BirthYear = BirthYear;
}

public int getBirthYear() {
    return BirthYear;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public int Age(){
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int nowYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int nowMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int nowDay = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
int day = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if (nowMonth > BirthMonth);
return (nowYear - BirthYear);
}

public double getBMI(){
return (weight * 703)/(height * height);
}

public int MaxHeartRate(){
return 220-Age();
}

public double TargetHeartRate(){
return MaxHeartRate() * 0.85 + MaxHeartRate() * 0.5;
}
}
```

And here is the second part, the HealthProfileApp part:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class HealthProfileApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String DoB;
    String theMonth;
    String theDay;
    String theYear;
    char gender;
    int Month;
    int Day;
    int Year;
    double height = 0.0;
    double weight;
   HealthProfile personalInfo = new HealthProfile();
   System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
   firstName = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
   lastName = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Male or female: ");
   gender = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
   System.out.println("Enter your date of birth in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
   DoB = input.nextLine();
   theMonth = DoB.substring(0,2);
   theDay = DoB.substring(3,5);
   theYear = DoB.substring(6,10);
   Month = Integer.parseInt(theMonth);
   Day = Integer.parseInt(theDay);
   Year = Integer.parseInt(theYear);
   System.out.println("Enter your height in inches: ");
   height = input.nextInt();
   personalInfo.setHeight((int) height);
   System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
   weight = input.nextInt();
   personalInfo.setWeight((int) weight);
   System.out.println("Name: " + personalInfo.getFirstName() +        personalInfo.getLastName());
   System.out.println("Gender: " + personalInfo.getGender());
   System.out.println("DoB: " + personalInfo.getBirthMonth() + "/" + personalInfo.getBirthDay() + "/" + personalInfo.getBirthYear());
   System.out.println("Height: " + personalInfo.getHeight());
   System.out.println("Weight: " + personalInfo.getWeight());
   System.out.println("Age: " + personalInfo.Age());
   System.out.println("BMI: " + personalInfo.getBMI());
   System.out.printf("Max heart rate: ", personalInfo.MaxHeartRate());
   System.out.printf("Target heart rate: ",         personalInfo.TargetHeartRate());
   System.out.println(" ");
   System.out.println( "BMI VALUES" );
    System.out.println("Underweight: Under 18.5");
    System.out.println("Normal: 18.5-24.9 ");
    System.out.println("Overweight: 25-29.9");
    System.out.println("Obese: 30 or over");
}
}
```

And finally, this is the output. My name doesn't display, neither does my gender, date of birth and my age is displaying 2015. If you have any input it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Name: nullnull
Gender: 
DoB: 0/0/0
Height: 69.0
Weight: 125.0
Age: 2015
BMI: 18.0
Max heart rate: Target heart rate:
BMI VALUES
Underweight: Under 18.5
Normal: 18.5-24.9
Overweight: 25-29.9
Obese: 30 or over
```

UPDATE: I fixed the name problem. But my gender and age are still way off. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You should not give your variables names that start with a capital letter. It won't stop your code from compiling but it is culturally important.

Comment: Don't give my variables names that start with a capital letter? Like my String Variables?

Comment: Any variables. e.g. int BirthMonth; is considered bad. Use int birthMonth; instead.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the setfirstname method.

You let the user enter their first name and last name. And then you do nothing with them. So when you call the getfirstname and getlastname method, it will return null.

**UPDATE**

Here you let the user enter first and last name:

```
 System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
   firstName = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
   lastName = input.nextLine();
```

You have to add this:

```
personalInfo.setFirstName(firstName);
personalInfo.setLastName(lastName);
```

Exactly what you have done with the length and the other methods.

Comment: I thought I did?  Where do I need to call this method? I'm sorry for the questions, I've just put a couple hours into this and it's way over my head I feel like.

edit: I called the setFirstName on line 32 of the HealthProfile. I called both First and Last, with set and get methods both?

Comment: You have declared the methods but you never use them, see my ypdated answer, just add those two methods right under the lastName = input.nextLine(); method :)

Comment: I did this! And it cannot find the symbol. So it doesn't have enough information to process the code.

Comment: @darkfireinsanity it's the same thing with gender, the user enter its gender, but you do not call the set gender method.

Comment: Thank you so much Johan. Now I'm just having trouble getting my DoB set, and my age correct. You're explaining things in terms I understand, I appreciate that.

Comment: @darkfireinsanity Glad to hear :) It is the samething there, you have to call the set birth month and set birth day. try adding those methods too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
personalInfo.setFirstName(firstName);
```

after these 2 lines

```
  System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
   firstName = input.nextLine();
```

and same for `LastName`

```
personalInfo.setLastName(lastName);
```

Because untill and unless you will set the reference variable : `firstName` and `lastName` , the default value of those will remain null as the default value of `instance` and `static` **Reference Variable** is null .

that is why your output is null null

---

For Calculation of Age You can use 3rd Party Library **JODA**

```
int month=Integer.parseInt(theMonth);
int day= Integer.parseInt(theDay);
int year=Integer.parseInt(theYear);

LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (year,month,day); //Birth date
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();                    //Today's date
Period period = new Period(birthdate, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());

//Now access the values as below
System.out.println(period.getDays());
System.out.println(period.getMonths());
System.out.println(period.getYears());
```

Now you can set the age in terms of above variables and then try to get them using getters method

Comment: Okay, I tried this earlier and it said "Error: cannot find symbol"

So I don't know what symbol it is referring to. 

I added  this to line 21, right under where you said.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack Trace So that we can help better

Comment: When you say the entire stack Trace, what are you referring to?

Comment: Complete Error you are getting , java Exception will surely point out of which symbol the compiler couldn't find out

Comment: I actually fixed the name problem. The problem I have now is my gender is not showing nor is my age correct.

Comment: Gender is not showing because you haven't call the `setGender` Method , you have to call same as you set the `firstName`

Comment: Thank you. I got that figured out.

Now to get the Calculation of Age, do I need to completely remove mine and try what you put?

Comment: You haven't calculated the age untill yet , So no need to remove any part of your code ,and i suggest you to understand how we cacluate the age instead just copying the above , It's for you own benefit

Comment: Alright, I have the public int Age () {

So I haven't even calculated the age?

Comment: Sorry. I have read my java book. My professor is completely useless. Thank you for the help.